# SHA-1 Hash of uploaded xls file always different, With csv file hashing works

Tags: c#, wcf, sha1

I got the following problem. I upload csv and excel files via WCF Service. Hash calculation does only work for csv files. With xls files i get a different value with every upload.

Hash Calculation:

```
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(datei.FullName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
                byte[] retVal = sha1.ComputeHash(file);
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var b in retVal)
                    sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));

                return sb.ToString();
            }
```

Does anybody know where the problem might be located? Is it a problem with the binary xls file format?

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Marius

Comment: Run a diff between the 2 XLS files. Perhaps Excel or Windows is updating something like a timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suspect the file is *actually different* each time. That's easy enough to check though - there are various free tools around to perform checksums/hashes. You could pick SHA1 and compare it with your own results, or use an MD5 tool etc.

Try running it both client side and server side - that way you'll be able to verify that the file itself hasn't been corrupted in transit.

Once you've worked out exactly where and when the file has changed, you'll need to decide what to do about it. For example, if Excel *is* adding a timestamp, you may want to mask that out when computing the hash.

Comment: I verified  the checksums with JDigest. And in fact i receive the same hashcodes which I calculated before with C#.

Comment: @user631833: Do you mean you verified them against the files you received, or the original files on the client?

Comment: the file on the client has a different hash value than the uploaded file. The calculated hashcodes are correct so in fact there are changes within the file. Since there is no transformation with excel of any kind, I am clueless where the changes are made. The calculation does not consider filenames or modified timestamps, or does it?

Comment: @user631833: No, the hash doesn't include the filename. So it's in the uploading process somehow. Is the file even the right size? What does your file upload code look like?